# audio(sound) is missing in licode recorded *.mkv files

Tags: licode

I am using licode docker latest image on my machine to run and test licode video recording feature.
The recording feature is working as expected only audio is missing in recored *.mkv file. 
I have already cross checked the configuration part. Audio in config is  true while making the connection with erizo.
localStream.hasAudio() return the true. So i have no idea what i am missing here.